# How can I reference a local JSON file in perl on a linux box?

Tags: json, perl

How can I reference the json file that I have locally stored? I am trying to access this with perl. For example, how can I access longitude and latitude from this json file?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON qw(decode_json);

$address = '/address_verification.json';
my $json=decode_json($address);

print $json
```

Here is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "input_index": 0,
    "candidate_index": 0,
    "delivery_line_1": "XXX XX XXXth Rd",
    "last_line": "Utica IL XXXXX-XXXX",
    "delivery_point_barcode": "456529758",
    "components": {
      "primary_number": "XXXX",
      "street_predirection": "X",
      "street_name": "XXXth",
      "street_suffix": "Rd",
      "city_name": "XXXX",
      "default_city_name": "XXXX",
      "state_abbreviation": "XX",
      "zipcode": "XXXXXX",
      "plus4_code": "XXXX",
      "delivery_point": "XX",
      "delivery_point_check_digit": "X"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "record_type": "X",
      "zip_type": "Standard",
      "county_fips": "XXXXXX",
      "county_name": "XXXXXXX",
      "carrier_route": "XXXXX",
      "congressional_district": "XX",
      "rdi": "Residential",
      "elot_sequence": "XXXX",
      "elot_sort": "X",
      "latitude": 55.555,
      "longitude": -55.5555,
      "precision": "XXXX",
      "time_zone": "XXXXX",
      "utc_offset": -5,
      "dst": true
    },
    "analysis": {
      "dpv_match_code": "X",
      "dpv_footnotes": "XXXXX",
      "dpv_cmra": "X",
      "dpv_vacant": "X",
      "active": "X",
      "footnotes": "X#"
    }
  }
]
```

I keep returning the following error:

```
malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "/address_verificatio...") at ./validateaddress.ajax line 8.
```

The directory is roughly built out in this manner:

```
HTML
-->CSS
-->Modules
---->Weather
------>address_verification.json
------>file_calling_json.file
```

Comment: `/address_verification.json` refers to a file in the root directory. You said your file was in `HTML/CSS/Modules/Weather`. You need to either refer to the file with an absolute address, or a valid relative address. Also, you probably need to read the file properly. Refer to the documentation.

Comment: Also, `decode_json` expects JSON, not a file system path. You need to open the file, read it, and pass its contents to `decode_json` rather than just passing the file name.

Comment: @ikegami How is that properly done? I had originally specified the path but got the same issue. The true path of the document is /var/www/html/modules/weather but I kept returning malformed json errors.

Comment: The "malformed JSON" error is because `decode_json()` expects to be passed a string containing JSON. It does not expect a filename. It is your responsibility to open the file and read the JSON from the file. You can then pass that JSON string to `decode_json()` and get back a Perl data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file name `/address_verification.json` seems to be using an incorrect path. This refers to a file found in the root directory. The file path must be either absolute, or a valid path relative to the directory the Perl program is run from.

E.g. if you run your program from the directory `HTML` in your example, you could refer to the file as `Modules/Weather/address_verification.json`.

Besides that, you need to read the json file into a Perl variable before you can decode it. Example of how that is done below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $address = 'address_verification.json';
my $txt = do {                             # do block to read file into variable
    local $/;                              # slurp entire file
    open my $fh, "<", $address or die $!;  # open for reading
    <$fh>;                                 # read and return file content
};
my $json = decode_json($txt);

print Dumper $json
```

On my system, with your sample file, it prints:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            'components' => {
                              'primary_number' => 'XXXX',
                              'delivery_point' => 'XX',
                              'plus4_code' => 'XXXX',
                              'street_predirection' => 'X',
                              'street_name' => 'XXXth',
                              'zipcode' => 'XXXXXX',
                              'street_suffix' => 'Rd',
                              'default_city_name' => 'XXXX',
                              'state_abbreviation' => 'XX',
                              'delivery_point_check_digit' => 'X',
                              'city_name' => 'XXXX'
                            },
            'delivery_point_barcode' => '456529758',
            'last_line' => 'Utica IL XXXXX-XXXX',
            'analysis' => {
                            'dpv_footnotes' => 'XXXXX',
                            'dpv_vacant' => 'X',
                            'dpv_match_code' => 'X',
                            'active' => 'X',
                            'dpv_cmra' => 'X',
                            'footnotes' => 'X#'
                          },
            'candidate_index' => 0,
            'metadata' => {
                            'elot_sort' => 'X',
                            'elot_sequence' => 'XXXX',
                            'county_fips' => 'XXXXXX',
                            'longitude' => '-55.5555',
                            'congressional_district' => 'XX',
                            'rdi' => 'Residential',
                            'carrier_route' => 'XXXXX',
                            'zip_type' => 'Standard',
                            'record_type' => 'X',
                            'utc_offset' => -5,
                            'latitude' => '55.555',
                            'time_zone' => 'XXXXX',
                            'county_name' => 'XXXXXXX',
                            'dst' => bless( do{\(my $o = 1)}, 'JSON::XS::Boolean' ),
                            'precision' => 'XXXX'
                          },
            'input_index' => 0,
            'delivery_line_1' => 'XXX XX XXXth Rd'
          }
        ];
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. To iterate through the hash now, I must navigate the keys. This would look something like...for my $i ($json){print $i->{"components"};}....correct?

Comment: Well, no, you have an array `[` which contains a hash `{`, which contains a mix of other values. You probably want to do `for my $hash (@$json) { for my $key (keys %$hash) { print $hash->{$key}`

Comment: The following is trying to access the metadata array. Am I calling the keys improperly?
for my $hash (@$json){
  for my $key(sort keys %$hash){
    for my $metadata(sort keys %{$hash{$key}{'metadata'}}){
      print $metadata,"\n";
    }
  }
}

Comment: @senicad If you have a question about how to use Perl datastructures, check the Perl documentation, or ask a new question.

Comment: I always use `<:raw` just in case someone has messed with the default encodings.

Comment: @briandfoy Does that help?